# How to forward MDC to ReactorClientHttpConnector

Tags: java, spring, webclient, mdc

I want log mdc by webclient logger

```
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
        .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.create()
                .wiretap("reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient", LogLevel.DEBUG,
                        AdvancedByteBufFormat.TEXTUAL, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)))

MDC.put("mdctest", "mdcvalue");

String response = webClient.get()
        .uri("http://api.geonames.org/countryCodeJSON?formatted=true&lat=47.03&lng=10.2&username=demo&style=full")
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(String.class)
        .block();
logger.info(response);
```

How I can forward MDC to reactor threads?
I tried https://ttddyy.github.io/mdc-with-webclient-in-webmvc/ but it's not worked, log happen before onNext.

Answer (score 0):

Read and understand this series of 3 blogs:
https://spring.io/blog/2023/03/28/context-propagation-with-project-reactor-1-the-basics